# Fiber.yield using ||

Tags: ruby, concurrency, fibers

I would like some help with the following code:

```
sg = Fiber.new do
    s = 0
    loop do
        square = s * s
        s += 1
        s = Fiber.yield(square) || s
    end
end

puts sg.resume
puts sg.resume
puts sg.resume
puts sg.resume 40
puts sg.resume
puts sg.resume 0
puts sg.resume
puts sg.resume
```

When run, outputs:

```
0
1
4
1600
1681
0
1
4
```

How does line 6 **s = Fiber.yield(square) || s** work? I think I understand the component parts just not what the line as a whole is doing. (Is there an alternative way of writing this that might better help me understand?).

(Edit: This code is a very slightly modified example from page 295 'Beginning Ruby, From Novice to Professional 2nd Ed' by Peter Cooper.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs for [`yield`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Fiber.html#method-c-yield)

> Any arguments passed to the next `resume` will be the value that this `Fiber.yield` expression evaluates to.

The line

```
s = Fiber.yield(square) || s
```

assigns the argument passed to `resume` to `s`. If that value is `nil` (or the argument is missing), `s` is re-assiged to `s` (i.e. it doesn't change).

Example:

```
sg.resume       #=> s = nil || s
                #=> s = s

sg.resume 40    #=> s = 40  || s
                #=> s = 40
```

Another way to write it is:

```
result = Fiber.yield(square)
s = result if result
```

Comment: Yes the example is very useful. Would I be wrong in thinking that during each sg.resume, line 6 is actually run before lines 4 and 5?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Yes, with the exception of the very first `sg.resume`. That one starts running the fiber, beginning with `s = 0`. The code runs until `Fiber.yield(square)` which returns `square`'s value (`0`) to `sg.resume` where it is printed. The fiber's execution is halted at that point, i.e. `s = [waiting for next resume] || s`. The second `puts sg.resume` resumes the fiber, passing `nil`. The assignment can be executed (`s = nil || s`) and the loop starts again.